# Getting the content of Joomla page into Rails page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, joomla

I have a web page created in Joomla. How do I get the content of that page into my Rails app's page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your hint @chrisBarretto. There wasn't any rss feed associated with the joomla page. However, I managed to grab the content from Joomla page with just using Nokogiri.

Here's what I did in the controller :

```
 @page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(" ... <joomla page url>..."))
```

Then in the view,

```
<%=raw @page.css("body table").first.to_s :%>
```

This worked perfectly as I wanted to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you used joomla, then you can just grab the rss feed from the page and parse the xml with Nokogiri.

https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri

Comment: How do I grab the rss feed of that particular page in rails?

Comment: All your out-of-the-box blogs usually have associated rss feeds to them. Can you post the url? The rss feed is just a url that returns xml or json

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same db for both, simply create a rails model to read that db table, and bring the content in.

OTOH, if you're wanting Joomla to assemble and create the entire page, then pass it to rails to view unmodified, why force Rails into the mix at all and just let some pages be rendered by Joomla and some by Rails? You'll need some creativity in the routing and positioning, but then you'll need that to do the RSS read mentioned above, anyway.